# How to have a case parameter in shell scripting that is followed by a different parameter?

Tags: linux, shell-script, case

I want the user to type in `-s` followed by a number (e.g. `-s 3`). However, I can't seem to be passing another variable next to the existing `-s`. This is my code:

```
echo choose
read choice 
       case $choice in 
       -a) echo you chose a 
        ;;
       -s $num) echo you chose the number $num #this is the -s number (e.g. -s 3) choice.
        ;;
      esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement options to a script by chance?

Comment: @Jesse_b I am trying to make the user type in '-s number' where number is any number he might want. For example -s 4

Comment: Seems like an x-y problem though, what is the ultimate goal for this code?

Comment: @Jesse_b this is a smaller problem of a bigger project. It's one of the project's instuctions: I want the user to type in a letter followed by a number so with e.g. -s 4 I want to show the contents of a file with their 4 column sorted

Comment: How many digits is the number allowed to be?

Comment: @Jesse_b only one. I have 4 columns so the number has to be 1,2,3 or 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost certainly a better way to handle what you're doing.  For starters you should avoid prompting the user for any input and instead make them provide arguments on the command line while running the program, but modifying your code to work:

```
read -rp 'choose: ' choice 
case $choice in 
    -a) echo 'you chose a';;
    -s\ [1-4]) "echo you chose the number ${choice#"-s "}";;
esac
```

Your `num` variable doesn't appear to be set so it will expand to nothing making your case pattern simply `-s )` and `-s 4` wont match `-s )` because...well they aren't the same.  So we need to modify that to expect a number after it (`-s\ [1-4])`).  Then we use parameter expansion to remove the `-s`.

---

The way I would handle it would be to use `getopts` similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts as: opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) printf '%s\n' 'You have chosen: a';;
        s) n=$OPTARG; printf '%s: %d\n' 'You have chosen s with an argument of' "$n";;
    esac
done
```

With this you would run specify the arguments on the command line such as:

```
./script.sh -s 4
```

Comment: thank you so much! That was really helpful! :)

Comment: @MargaritaK: don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" if you are satisfied with it. If so, please mark the answer with a green mark next to its author's name and the points' counter.y

Comment: @Jesse_b hello, how could I convert the code to take a word as input? (e.g. -s Nick). thank you in advance