# How to have a second parameter word as input from the user

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have this snippet: The logic behind it, is that I want the user to enter -s followed by a word (e.g. -s dog). However, it doesn't work.

```
read -rp 'choose: ' choice 
case $choice in 
     -a) echo you chose a;;
     -s [a-z]+) echo you chose the word ${choice#"-s "};;
esac
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read two words using `read`, then use two variables:

```bash
read -r -p 'Enter "-a" or "-s <word>": ' opt word
case $opt in
    -a)
        echo 'You picked "-a"'
        ;;
    -s) 
        printf 'You picked "-s" with the word "%s"\n' "$word"
        ;;
    *)
        echo 'You picked neither "-a" nor "-s <word>"'
esac
```

The reason your code is not working is because you are using an extended regular expression as the pattern (`-s [a-z]+`).  The patterns used by the `case` statement are filename globbing patterns.  They are similar but not the same.  A globbing pattern does not allow for the same sort of "repetition modifier" that a regular expression pattern uses (the `+`).

With a globbing pattern, you would be able to use `'-s '[a-z]*`, i.e. "the string `-s`  followed by a lower case letter, and then *something*" (the same as `^-s [a-z].*` with a regular expression).

Comment: thank you for answering but this is a smaller part of a bigger project and the word has to be next to the -s parameter. How can I do the same thing but in the -s ...) bracket?

Comment: @MargaritaK See updated answer, which contains a suggestion. I'm not sure what you mean by "next to".  The user would enter a string, like `-s someword`.  Here, `-s` is "next to" `someword`.  I'm also a bit confused why you are using `read` to read things that look like command line options.

Comment: thank you so much, I tried the 'opt word' and it seems to be working properly. I'm new to shell programming so that's why I used read to read these things. It's also a rule that I have to follow for the project

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the space character (like in [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557268/332764) to your previous question).

Bash interprets the `+` as a literal `+` and not as "one or more occurrences". Bash's 
pattern matching operators are different from regular expressions. 
To match one or more occurrences, you could enable the "extended globbing" `extglob` shell option and use the `+(...)` pattern.

To make sure the range expression `[a-z]` only matches lowercase letters (this might depend on your locale's `LC_COLLATE` or `LC_ALL` setting), you could also enable the `globasciiranges` shell option.

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s globasciiranges

read -rp 'choose: ' choice
case $choice in
     -a)
        echo "you chose a"
        ;;
     -s\ +([a-z]))
        echo "you chose the word \"${choice#-s }\""
        ;;
     *) echo "unknown choice \"$choice\""
esac
```

Related:

- [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) (Bash Reference Manual)

Answer (score 0):

There can not be an (unquoted) space on the `…)` part of a case statement.

So, you need to quote it: `\`, `" "` or `' '`:

Also, the matching on case statements is done by patterns, not regexes. There is no `+` in **Pattern Matching**, there is only `*`, but that doesn't mean repetition of last element but simply "any character in any count". I'll assume that your `[a-z]+` was intended to match a word made of only lowercase letters. It is not possible to write the same in simpler pattern matching strings. What could be done is:

```
read -rp 'choose: ' choice 
case $choice in 
     -a)           echo "you chose a";;
     -s\ *[^a-z]*) echo "not a valid word selected";;
     -s\ *)        echo "you chose the word ${choice#"-s "}";;
     *)            echo "no choice made";;
esac
```

Comment: @Freddy, thank you for answering!! How can I make the command have this input and still work? (e.g. user input: -d\ * -r) echo the word is ${choice#"-d -r"};;

Comment: thank you for answering!! How can I make the command have this input and still work? (e.g. user input: -d\ * -r) echo the word is ${choice#"-d -r"};;